# Change color of specific title with jquery

Tags: jquery, otrs

Im looking to change title text color if title is equal to specific text. In this case i try to change color, when title is "Guilherme". Some help?

Part of webpage link:

> xpto.com/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketID=17564

Html code:

[image]

jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const Action = Core.Config.Get("Action");
    const SupportedActions = ["AgentTicketZoom"];
    if ($.inArray(Action, SupportedActions) !== -1) {
      if (Action === "AgentTicketZoom") {
        $("label:contains('Firstname:')").hide()       
        changeColor();
      }
    }

    function changeColor() {
      $("select[title='Firstname:']"){
        if ($(this).find('.Guilherme').length > 0){
          $(this).css("color", "red");
        }
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect to happen. What to select and how it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set colours via css using attribute selectors:

```css
p[title=Guilherme] {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<label>Firstname:</label>
<p class='Value FixedValueSmall' title="Guilherme">
  Guilherme
</p>
<p class='Value FixedValueSmall' title="Not Guilherme">
  Not Guilherme
</p>
```

If you're intent on using jquery, the same selectors can be used:

```js
$("p[title=Guilherme]").addClass("red");

// or .css if you don't like classes
//$("p[title=Guilherme]").css("color", "red");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Firstname:</label>
<p class='Value FixedValueSmall' title="Guilherme">
  Guilherme
</p>
<p class='Value FixedValueSmall' title="Not Guilherme">
  Not Guilherme
</p>
```